# azure function receiving iothub messages and saving into CosmoDB

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, iot

I have a demo of a gateway device sending multiple messages to iotHub at a rate of ~1-2 messages per second.

I have an azure function hooked up this as a trigger, and the function will parse through the message and save it to the appropriate collection in a cosmos db.

The problem I am having is that it randomly crashes or when it runs for a while it only receives a couple messages at a time and then goes inactive for couple minutes before it comes back. Meaning that the my frontend (application) has very outdated information being read into from cosmoDB.

The reason I chose this architecture was because Microsoft recommends this style for 'hot storage' and real time applications, but it is quite the opposite.

What tips or pointers can you give me to make this more efficient and way faster, I must be missing something.

Comment: first thing we need to know is why is the application crashing?

Comment: how should we help you without any relevant code, logs, error messages?

Comment: In general: If all you need to do is writing data from IoT Hub into Cosmos DB, why not just use Azure Stream Analytics?

Comment: Azure Stream Analytics? I will look into this now, can you give me a quick summary of the main differences of this vs what I am using?

Comment: @silent I sometimes get: 
Timeout value of 00:05:00 exceeded by function 'Functions.IoTHub_EventHub1' (Id: '36197891-9477-4782-bb59-2f54965321c6'). Initiating cancellation.

but the main problem I have is that it does not run continously, it works in batches. It receives ~5-8 messages per run and then pauses (even though there are still messages being sent) and a couple minutes later just grabs another batch and executes.

Comment: Again, please post some code